# How to prevent a supplier from upvoting and downvoting himself

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I am working on a Supplier Management System. I have a page where users could view all suppliers on the application. on the same page, users can upvote and downvote suppliers, is there a way that i could make the supplier not able to upvote or downvote his self.

I am thinking if there is a way i can pass the supplier.user into the context which identifies the supplier, perhaps doing something like this but it doesn't seem to work. I could then pass this into the template {% if supplier.user == request.user %}content...{% endif %}

Presently, supplier.user return nothing.

views.py

```
def Viewsupplier(request):
    title = "All Suppliers"
    suppliers = User.objects.filter(user_type__is_supplier=True)

    # Get the updated count:
    suppliers_votes_count = {}
    for supplier in suppliers:
        upvote_count = supplier.upvotes
        downvote_count = supplier.downvotes
        supplier_count = {supplier: {'upvote': upvote_count, 'downvote': downvote_count } }
        suppliers_votes_count.update(supplier_count)

    context = {"suppliers":suppliers, "title":title, "suppliers_votes_count": suppliers_votes_count}
    return render(request, 'core/view-suppliers.html', context)
```

view-supplier.html

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Votes</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    {% for supplier in suppliers %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
        <td>{{supplier.email}}</td>
        <td>
            <div class="table-data-feature">
                {% if supplier.user == request.user %}<a href="{% url 'upvote' supplier.id %}">{% endif %}
                    <button class="item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Like">
                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-thumb-up"></i></button>
                {% if supplier.user == request.user %}</a>{% endif %}
                &nbsp;<button>{{supplier.upvotes}}</button>&nbsp;
                {% if supplier.user == request.user %}<a href="{% url 'downvote' supplier.id %}">{% endif %}
                    <button class="item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Dislike">
                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-thumb-down"></i></button>
                {% if supplier.user == request.user %}</a>{% endif %}
                &nbsp;<button>{{supplier.downvotes}}</button>&nbsp;
            </div>                                                  
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% empty %}
        <tr><td class="text-center p-5" colspan="7"><h4>No supplier available</h4></td></tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by using this templatetag in my templates:

`{% if supplier.email != request.user.email %}content...{% endif %}`

This worked easily because i already had the supplier info from the views already.